# extracting the 2 words before, the actual word, and the 2 strings after a specific string in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas series

```
       Explanation 

a      "how are you doing today where is she going" 
b      "do you like blueberry ice cream does not make sure " 
c      "this works but you know that the translation is on"
```

I want to extract the 2 words before and after the string "you"

for example, I want it to be something like

```
        Explanation                                                    Explanation Extracted

a      "how are you doing today where is she going"                  "how are you doing today"
b      "do you like blueberry ice cream does not make sure "         do you like blueberry ice 
c      "this works but you know that the translation is on"           "work but you know that"
```

This regex expression gives me the the two words before and after "you", but doesn't include "you" itself

```
(?P<before>(?:\w+\W+){,2})you\W+(?P<after>(?:\w+\W+){,2})
```

How do I change it so I can have "you" included

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df['Explanation Extracted'] = df['Explanation'].str.extract(r'\b((?:\w+\W+){0,2}you\b(?:\W+\w+){0,2})', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o4iSUq/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\w+\W+){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrences of one or more word chars and then one or more non-word chars
- `you` - a `you` string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\W+\w+){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrences of one or more non-word chars and then one or more word chars.

A Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Explanation':["how are you doing today where is she going", "do you like blueberry ice cream does not make sure ", "this works but you know that the translation is on"]})
>>> df['Explanation Extracted'] = df['Explanation'].str.extract(r'\b((?:\w+\W+){0,2}you\b(?:\W+\w+){0,2})', expand=False)
>>> df
                                         Explanation    Explanation Extracted
0         how are you doing today where is she going  how are you doing today
1  do you like blueberry ice cream does not make ...    do you like blueberry
2  this works but you know that the translation i...  works but you know that
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show a way with no regex and no pandas, for this case I dont see it needed.

```
text1 = "how are you doing today where is she going"
text2 = "do you like blueberry ice cream does not make sure "
text3 = "this works but you know that the translation is on"


def show_trunc_sentence(text, word='you'): # here you can choose another word besides you but you is the default
    word_loc = int(text.split().index('you'))
    num = [word_loc - 2 if word_loc - 2 >= 0 else 0]
    num = int(num[0])
    before = text.split()[num: word_loc + 1]
    after = text.split()[word_loc + 1:word_loc + 3]
    print(" ".join(before + after))


    show_trunc_sentence(text2)
```

Outputs :
text1 - how are you doing today
text2 - do you like blueberry
text3 - works but you know that